# Custom button not changing text color when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I have created 3 custom buttons using for loop. But when I select a button the text color is not changing.How do I do it? What else I have to add?

Here is my Code

```
buttonText = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"Slambook",@"Initiated",@"Collaborated",nil];    
NSInteger numControllers = [viewControllerArray count];

for (int i = 0; i<numControllers; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+i*(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers-X_OFFSET, Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers, HEIGHT);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTitle:[buttonText objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [navigationView addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: You want to change text colour on button click??

Comment: What's the `.normal` color and how do you set that? This is the default color. If this is different, there's something wrong that is now shown above, because the above code correctly sets the color you should see when tapping the button.

Comment: @meaning-matters noramal color is set to black and on click I want to the button color , but it remains black

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff make sure your button's title is not attributed string

Comment: It is not an attributed string.

Comment: When I click it changes and again it is set to black. I think `UIControlStateHighlighted ` is working but `UIControlStateSelected ` is not working

Comment: But in your code i am seeing that you have not set title.

Comment: @MangeshMurhe. I had skipped while pasting. Now it is edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code for single button with dummy text , black text colour for normal state and button colour is highlighting on tap:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40,50 , 35);
//        button.frame = CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+i*(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers-X_OFFSET, Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers, HEIGHT);
    [button setTitle:@"Dummy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Below line does not change button text colour for long time, it change text colour of button for fraction of seconds after tap

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Try this:

```
 NSInteger numControllers = [viewControllerArray count];

    for (int i = 0; i<numControllers; i++) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+i*(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers-X_OFFSET, Y_BUFFER,(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers, HEIGHT);
   button.tag=i+200;
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackcolor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [navigationView addSubview:button];
    }
- (IBAction)tapButtonAction:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackcolor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   for (int i = 0; i<numControllers; i++) {
       UIButton *restBtn=[navigationView viewWithTag:i+200];
    if(restbtn!= btn)
    {
         [restBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:   UIControlStateNormal];
        [restBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackcolor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

    }
}
```

Comment: yeah . I have the same issue but want that color to stay until I select other button

Comment: I tried it there as @JatinRB Korat answer. but once it is set it is not setting back to unselected color when other button is tapped

Comment: I have edited answer here only.Try this.may you get some syntax error as i have edited code here only.But i hope it will solve your problem

Comment: It crashes saying `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTitleColor:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faeb741c400'` . I tried changing `[navigationView viewWithTag:i*200]` to `UIButton *restBtn= (UIButton *)[navigationView viewWithTag:i];` still it is crashing

Comment: You have passed only 'i', because of that tag is not matching.Use i*200 then only tag will match

Comment: While setting also I have set as `button.tag=i`

Comment: When you get button by using tag,  check type of btn object. It should be uibutton. By seeing crash log i think  button object is not type casted to Uibutton. It is remaining as UIView.

Comment: since I have 3 controllers it gives me 3 objects one of UIView and other two of UIButton

Comment: Can you post the comsole log??

Comment: `restBtn <UIView: 0x7fc98d7335c0; frame = (0 0; 375 70); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000023b840>>
2017-11-30 18:16:39.810246+0530 Wishfie[8200:284625] restBtn <UIButton: 0x7fc98d733ac0; frame = (117 14; 125 50); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000023a820>>
2017-11-30 18:16:39.810726+0530 Wishfie[8200:284625] restBtn <UIButton: 0x7fc98d735d20; frame = (242 14; 125 50); opaque = NO; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000023a800>>
` .  this is displayed in the log

Comment: This is because your other view and some buttons have similar tag. That's why i used i*200 to make unique tag. Change it to i*1000 at every place

Comment: HI Zeenath.Sry for mistake.Use i+200. It is working fine.Problem was with i*200 when i is 0.So tag for buttons set to 0, which is by default tag for UIView.Use i+200 .It is working.

Comment: I have also edited my answer.I hope you will get your solution this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSInteger numControllers = [viewControllerArray count];

    for (int i = 0; i<numControllers; i++) {

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(X_BUFFER+i*(self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers-X_OFFSET, Y_BUFFER, (self.view.frame.size.width-2*X_BUFFER)/numControllers, HEIGHT);
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackcolor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [navigationView addSubview:button];
    }
- (IBAction)tapButtonAction:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    if ([btn isSelected]) {
        [btn setSelected:NO];
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackcolor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
    {
        [btn setSelected:YES];
        [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:24.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

## change your for loop with this code

```
int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [viewControllerArray count]; i++){
        //int y=2;
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+2, 0, 40, 36)];

        id myArrayElement=[viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myArrayElement] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackcolor]];

        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];


        x += button.frame.size.width;

        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:137.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
```

Comment: It changes the color when clicked. But when I click on other buttons it remains the same color I want change the unselected to grey and other button is selected

Comment: some changes in tapButtonAction so refer it again